# How to change the shape of logits to match the shape of labels

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a custom dataset with 300 images:

- Each image has a shape of 192X192X3
- Its a classification problem with 3 possible labels
- The model is trained by providing data in batches of 20

I have made a graph in tensorflow, but when i try to train it i get `InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[720,3] labels_size=[20,3]`.

I know that the problem is that my logits [720,3] and labels [20,3] shapes are different, the issue im facing is why and where my logits gets the [720, 3] shape and how to change it accordingly. Changing layers, loss functions and batch size haven't solved it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

I have a `Train` class with af `build_graph()` and `train()` method.
Here is the full code:

```
class Train:
    __x_ = []
    __y_ = []
    __logits = []
    __loss = []
    __train_step = []
    __merged_summary_op = []
    __saver = []
    __session = []
    __writer = []
    __is_training = []
    __loss_val = []
    __train_summary = []
    __val_summary = []

def __init__(self):
    pass

def build_graph(self):
    self.__x_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 192, 192, 3], name='X')
    self.__y_ = tf.placeholder("int32", shape=[None, 3], name='Y')
    self.__is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)


    with tf.name_scope("model") as scope:
        conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=self.__x_, filters=64,
                                 kernel_size=[5, 5],
                                 padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu)
        pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

        conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool1, filters=64, kernel_size=[5, 5], padding="same",
                                 activation=tf.nn.relu)

        pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

        conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool2, filters=32, kernel_size=[5, 5], padding="same",
                                 activation=tf.nn.relu)

        pool3 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv3, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

        pool3_flat = tf.reshape(pool3, [-1, 4 * 4 * 32])

        # FC layers
        FC1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool3_flat, units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        FC2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=FC1, units=64, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        self.__logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=FC2, units=3)

        #Create variables to hold training loss __loss and validation loss 
        #__loss_val
        with tf.name_scope("loss_func") as scope:
            self.__loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=self.__logits, labels=self.__y_))
            self.__loss_val = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=self.__logits, labels=self.__y_))

            # Add loss to tensorboard
            self.__train_summary = tf.summary.scalar("loss_train", self.__loss)
            self.__val_summary = tf.summary.scalar("loss_val", self.__loss_val)


        with tf.name_scope("optimizer") as scope:
            global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
            starter_learning_rate = 1e-3
            # decay every 10000 steps with a base of 0.96 function
            learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate, global_step, 1000, 0.9,
                                                       staircase=True)
            self.__train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(self.__loss, global_step=global_step)
            tf.summary.scalar("learning_rate", learning_rate)
            tf.summary.scalar("global_step", global_step)


        # Merge op for tensorboard
        self.__merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
        # Build graph
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        # Saver for checkpoints
        self.__saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=None)


        # Configure summary to output at given directory
        self.__session = tf.Session()
        self.__writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./logs/flight_path", self.__session.graph)
        self.__session.run(init)



def train(self, save_dir='./save', batch_size=20):

    #Load dataset and labels
    x = np.asarray(di.load_images())
    y = np.asarray(di.load_labels())

    #Shuffle dataset
    np.random.seed(0)
    shuffled_indeces = np.arange(len(y))
    np.random.shuffle(shuffled_indeces)
    shuffled_x = x[shuffled_indeces].tolist()
    shuffled_y = y[shuffled_indeces].tolist()
    shuffled_y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(shuffled_y, 3)

    dataset = (shuffled_x, shuffled_y)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dataset)
    #dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=300)

    # Using Tensorflow data Api to handle batches
    dataset_train = dataset.take(200)
    dataset_train = dataset_train.repeat()
    dataset_train = dataset_train.batch(batch_size)

    dataset_test = dataset.skip(200)
    dataset_test = dataset_test.repeat()
    dataset_test = dataset_test.batch(batch_size)

    # Create an iterator
    iter_train = dataset_train.make_one_shot_iterator()
    iter_train_op = iter_train.get_next()
    iter_test = dataset_test.make_one_shot_iterator()
    iter_test_op = iter_test.get_next()

    # Build model graph
    self.build_graph()

    # Train Loop
    for i in range(10000):
        batch_train = self.__session.run([iter_train_op])
        batch_x_train, batch_y_train = batch_train[0]
        # Print loss from time to time
        if i % 100 == 0:
            batch_test = self.__session.run([iter_test_op])
            batch_x_test, batch_y_test = batch_test[0]
            loss_train, summary_1 = self.__session.run([self.__loss,
                                                    self.__merged_summary_op],
                                                   feed_dict={self.__x_:
                                                                  batch_x_train,
                                                              self.__y_:
                                                                  batch_y_train,
                                                              self.__is_training: True})
            loss_val, summary_2 = self.__session.run([self.__loss_val,
                                              self.__val_summary],
                                             feed_dict={self.__x_: batch_x_test,
                                                        self.__y_: batch_y_test,
                                                        self.__is_training: False})
            print("Loss Train: {0} Loss Val: {1}".format(loss_train,
                                                 loss_val))
            # Write to tensorboard summary
            self.__writer.add_summary(summary_1, i)
            self.__writer.add_summary(summary_2, i)

        # Execute train op
        self.__train_step.run(session=self.__session, feed_dict={
            self.__x_: batch_x_train, 
            self.__y_: batch_y_train,
            self.__is_training: True})


    # Save model
    if not os.path.exists(save_dir):
        os.makedirs(save_dir)
        checkpoint_path = os.path.join(save_dir, "model")
        filename = self.__saver.save(self.__session, checkpoint_path)
        print("Model saved in file: %s" % filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cnn = Train()
    cnn.train()
```

Comment: When it comes to: `pool3_flat = tf.reshape(pool3, [-1, 4 * 4 * 32])`, how did you infer the numbers `4`, `4` and `32`?

Comment: Oh yeah thanks for pointing that out gorjan! The reason for the numbers 4, 4 and 32 is because this model was at first designed for the CIFAR10 dataset, so after the images went through the last pooling layer, the images had a shape of [4, 4, 32]. Now that i redesigned the model for other images I forgot to change the last reshaping op. I changed it to `tf.reshape(pool3, [-1, 24 * 24 * 32])`, and it works now. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Glad that I have been of help! One more suggestion. Instead of having the number hardcoded, do this:

`poo3_flat = tf.reshape(pool3, [-1, pool3.shape[1] * pool3.shape[2] * pool3.shape[3])`